# Test RSpec is not showing the error can't be blank it's showing the validates for minimum and rising error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, simple-form

I'm using simple_form so before I do the tests with rspec with the form_for default by rails.
I do all my specs and they pass.
So I install the simple_form with bootstrap styles, and then config for use the :full_error method.
And the tests who I write for the attributes (title and content) can't be blank. It's showing first the error messages who validates the minimum for the attribute title or content and complaining an error.
What I need to do? I erase this test or config something for keep this test.
So this is my model post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title,
              length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 100 },
              presence: true,
              uniqueness: true
```

this is my scenario on RSpec:

```
  scenario "title can't be blank" do
      click_button  "Create Post"

      expect(page).to have_content "Post has not been created."
      expect(page).to have_content "Title can't be blank"
    end

The failure it's complaining:
Failures:

  1) Users can create posts when providing invalid attributes title can't be blank
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "Title can't be blank"
       expected to find text "Title can't be blank" in "×Post has not been created.{\"alert\"=>\"Post has not been created.\"}New Post* TitleTitle is too short (minimum is 10 characters)Subtitle* Content Content is too short (minimum is 30 characters)"
```

Comment: Have you tried re-ordering the validation?  Try putting `presence: true,` BEFORE `length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 100 },`

Comment: Yes, this work's thank's SteveTurczyn!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So changed the order and works!

```
validates :title,
              presence: true,
              length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 100 },
              uniqueness: true
```